# Samba и права на каталоги

Tags: samba, linux

Вопрос дурацкий, из серии "знал, но забыл" :)

В smb.conf написано:

```
[root directory]# ...directory mask = 0777
```

Однако с удалённой машины каталоги в расшаренном месте создаются как 755. Почему?

Comment: Ответ тоже из серии "вроде помню", поэтому комент. Пробовали directory mode = 0777?

Comment: Вставил, рестартанул. Теперь 775 :)

Comment: не понял, не получилось?

Comment: Ну, что-то изменилось - было 755, стали создаваться как 775 :) Но всё равно не 777.

Comment: а под пользователем от которого создает, umask случайно не настроен?

Comment: klopp@ubuntu2:~$ umask    0002

Comment: не, samba то у вас скорее всего от другого пользователя запущена, вот у него надо umask посмотреть, хотя конешно это я скорее всего вангую.

Comment: Там "security = user" и юзер тот же самый :)

Comment: А самба от рута, да, там 0022.

Answer (score 1):

SAMBA        Global Settings

```
    security = share
    [public]
            comment = users_shared
        path = /public
        browsable = yes
        guest ok = yes
        public = yes
        writable = yes
       create mask = 0666
        directory mask = 0777
```

FSTAB

```
//10.19.12.1/public /mnt/users cifs username=user,password=pass,noperm,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,iocharset=utf8,_netdev 0 0
```